# Google Voice Actions, Home, Actions, Assistant

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

Please can somebody give a short summary/difference between Google Voice Actions, Home, Actions and Assistant (Dialogflow)? I would like to control my android java application via google assistant/home, but I'm having hard time finding something I can start with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building something for the Google Assistant, you will use [**Actions on Google**](http://actions.google.com). This is a cloud-based platform for AI-powered interactions. An *action* can take a user's intent, either through text or a transcription of what they said, and return a useful result.

Most people are not experts with natural language understanding, so they can use [**Dialogflow**](http://dialogflow.com). This service gives developers the ability to easily match the user's intent and identify entities through what they said.

Once you build an *action*, you can publish it for the [**Google Assistant**](https://assistant.google.com/). This is a platform that is available on a variety of *surfaces*. Surfaces include **Google Home** as well as your **phone**.

If you are interested in building a device that embeds the Google Assistant or want to add the Google Assistant to your application, you can use the [**Google Assistant SDK**](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/). This allows you to make requests to the Assistant and present the response to the user.

Depending on what you are building, the tools you will use can vary.